# Como capturar o evento de fechamento em um Stage?

Tags: java, javafx

Estou procurando um evento tipo o "windows close" do Swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode chamar o método [setOnCloseRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onCloseRequestProperty) do seu [Stage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html), dessa forma você pode executar uma ação assim que o usuário cliciar no botão para fechar a janela.

Ex.:

```
public class Teste extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> System.out.println("Fechando o programa"));

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```